# Using SQLBulkCopy and IDatareader with ColumnMappings

Tags: c#, asp.net, sqlbulkcopy, datareader

I would like to use a `DataReader` considering my file has millions of lines and a `DataTable` seems to be slow for loading with `SQLBulkCopy`

I implemented [this reader](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/1029831/Fast-and-Simple-IDataReader-Implementation-to-Read), which will read my file this way:

```
//snippet from CSVReader implementation
Read(); 
_csvHeaderstring = _csvlinestring;
_header = ReadRow(_csvHeaderstring);
int i = 0;
_csvHeaderstring = "";
foreach (var item in _header)//read each column and create a         dummy header.
{
    headercollection.Add("COL_" + i.ToString(), null);
    _csvHeaderstring = _csvHeaderstring + "COL_" + i.ToString() + _delimiter;
    i++;
}
_csvHeaderstring.TrimEnd(_delimiter);
_header = ReadRow(_csvHeaderstring);
Close(); //close and repoen to get the record position to beginning.
_file = File.OpenText(filePath);


public static void MyMethod()
{
    textDataReader rdr = new textDataReader(file, '\t', false);
    using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
    {

        bulkcopy.DestinationTableName = "[dbo].[MyTable]";
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_0", "DestinationCol1");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_1", "DestinationCol2");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_3", "DestinationCol3");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_4", "DestinationCol4");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_5", "DestinationCol5");
        bulkcopy.ColumnMappings.Add("COL_6", "DestinationCol6");
        bulkcopy.WriteToServer(rdr);
        bulkcopy.Close();
    }
}
```

However when trying to do a `SQLBulkCopy` columnmapping to skip the unecessary column I get the error:

> the given columnmapping does not match up with any column in the
>   source or destination.

I have also tried to map [this way](http://forums.asp.net/t/1855672.aspx?ColumnMapping%20in%20SQLBulkCopy%20doesn%20t%20match%20up) to no avail.

Will this implementation of `IDataReader` work for `SQLBulkCopy`? I tried implementing an 'ignore column' method but that didn't work.

Comment: How about [this solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38566285/5794617). If you need to ignore some columns, you have to add some lambda to CsvReader class

Comment: Here is my data reader for bulk insert from CSV. Maybe you'll see what's missing: https://github.com/docevaad/Chain/blob/master/Tortuga.Chain/Tortuga.Chain.Csv.source/shared/CsvDataReader.cs

Comment: And yes, DataTable is slow. I did a lot of benchmarking to prove that was a huge bottleneck back in my younger days.

Comment: Keep in mind my file does not have headers so that is why I liked this implementation.

Comment: @JonathanAllen I see your logic for unmapped columns, but not sure how to implement your class