# How to manage memory when loading a large text file to a DataTable

Tags: c#, memory-management, memory-leaks, datatable, out-of-memory

I wrote a process in C# which takes a `.tar.gz` file extracts its contents, two large text files, ~250+ MB. These two text files are simply comma separated value files. The two text files are loaded into a `DataTable` one at a time. After the first file is loaded into a data table, a SQL bulk copy is executed on that table. Then the second file is loaded into a data table and again, a SQL  bulk copy is executed on that table. This code runs fine on my machine where resources are plentiful. But when I move the executable over to a batch server, it starts throwing out of memory exceptions. After analyzing/profiling the execution of the code I see that it can reach and exceed 11 GB of memory until it finishes executing. I added some `DataTable.Clear()` calls followed by `GC.Collect()`. This helped. After the first table is loaded and during the SQL bulk copy memory consumption is ~4 GB. Then it drops to nearly 0. Then when the second file begins loading it consumes ~7 GB of memory and then drops to 0 when the SQL bulk copy is complete. However, I still feel this memory consumption is wickedly high. Especially for loading some simple comma separated files into a data table then to a SQL table. The execution of this takes approximately 5-7 minutes.

Here's a little detail on the two files if necessary.
The first file is 16 columns wide. With approximately 3 million records.
The second file is 4 columns wide. With approximately 1.3 billion records.

The two files both get read into data tables and the data of each column is casted to it's appropriate type, so `string` for strings, `int` for ints, `datetime` for dates and times, etc.

How can I go about getting the memory foot print of this app to be much smaller but still execute in a reasonable time?

Here's the logic that loads the data table and then performs SQL bulk copy.

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM " + DESTINATIONSCHEMA + ".KEY_TABLE";        
DataTable keyNameLookup = new DataTable();
const int FILEA_COLUMN_COUNT = 16;

using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING))
using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(query, sc)) {
    sc.Open();
    keyNameLookup.Load(cm.ExecuteReader());
    sc.Close();
}

foreach (string file in fileList) {
    if (file.Contains("FILE_A")) {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(file);
        DataTable dtKeyValues = new DataTable(file + "key_value");
        for (int col = 0; col < 4; col++)
            dtKeyValues.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        for (int col = 0; col < FILEA_COLUMN_COUNT + 1; col++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        using (FileStream fs = File.Open(Path.Combine(DOWNLOADDESTINATION, file), FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
        using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs)) {
            string line;
            while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> kvPairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
                var cols = line.Split('~');
                DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
                dr[0] = DateTime.Now;
                for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < FILEA_COLUMN_COUNT; cIndex++) {
                    if (cIndex >= 0 && cIndex <= 6) {
                        if (cIndex == 5) dr[cIndex + 1] = (cols[cIndex] == "") ? Convert.ToDateTime(loadDate) : Convert.ToDateTime(cols[cIndex]);
                        else dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
                    } else if (cIndex > 6) {
                        if (cIndex == 10) { // key value column
                            dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
                            string[] keyValues = cols[cIndex].Split(',');
                            string[] keyNames = cols[cIndex - 1].Split(',');
                            if (keyValues.Length == keyNames.Length) {
                                for (int i = 0; i < keyNames.Length; i++) {
                                    kvPairs.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(keyNames[i], keyValues[i]));
                                }
                            }

                            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> kv in kvPairs) {
                                var res = from lookupRows in keyNameLookup.AsEnumerable()
                                            where lookupRows.Field<string>("KEY_NAME") == kv.Key
                                            select lookupRows;
                                DataRow drKv = dtKeyValues.NewRow();
                                drKv[0] = dr[0];
                                drKv[1] = Convert.ToInt32(dr[1]);
                                drKv[2] = res.First().Field<Int16>("KEY_NAME_ID");
                                drKv[3] = kv.Value;
                                dtKeyValues.Rows.Add(drKv);
                            }
                        } else dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
                    }
                }
                dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            }

            using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
                sc.Open();
                using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sc)) {
                    sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 6000;
                    sbc.DestinationTableName = DESTINATIONSCHEMA + ".MAIN";
                    try {
                    List<int> maxLengths =
                        Enumerable.Range(0, dt.Columns.Count)
                        .Select(col => dt.AsEnumerable()
                            .Select(row => row[col]).OfType<string>()
                            .Max(val => val.Length)).ToList();
                        sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error writing datatable to " + sbc.DestinationTableName + " table in database.");
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + e);
                    }

                    sbc.DestinationTableName = DESTINATIONSCHEMA + ".KEY_VALUE_TABLE";
                    try {
                        sbc.WriteToServer(dtKeyValues);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Console.WriteLine("Error writing datatable to " + sbc.DestinationTableName + " table in database.");
                        Console.WriteLine("\t" + e);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
        dtKeyValues.Clear();
        dtKeyValues.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
    } else if (file.Contains("FILE_B")) {
        const int FILEB_COLUMN_COUNT = 4;
        DataTable dt = new DataTable(file);
        for (int i = 0; i <= FILEB_COLUMN_COUNT; i++)
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn());
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Path.Combine(DOWNLOADDESTINATION, file));
        string line = string.Empty;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null) {
            var cols = line.Split('~');
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = DateTime.Now;
            for (int cIndex = 0; cIndex < FILEB_COLUMN_COUNT; cIndex++) {
                if (cIndex == 0) dr[cIndex + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(cols[cIndex]);
                else if (cIndex == 1) dr[cIndex + 1] = Convert.ToInt32(cols[cIndex]);
                else dr[cIndex + 1] = cols[cIndex];
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        }
        sr.Close();
        using (SqlConnection sc = new SqlConnection(CONNECTIONSTRING)) {
            sc.Open();
            using (SqlBulkCopy sbc = new SqlBulkCopy(sc)) {
                sbc.BulkCopyTimeout = 6000;
                sbc.DestinationTableName = DESTINATIONSCHEMA + ".AUX_TABLE";
                try {
                    sbc.WriteToServer(dt);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Console.WriteLine("Error writing datatable to table in database.");
                    Console.WriteLine("\t" + e);
                }
            }
        }

        dt.Clear();
        dt.Dispose();
        GC.Collect();
    }
}
return true;
```

Comment: Maybe you should try to do this bulkcopy on smaller parts of data? i.e. like every 1000 lines push this to SQL database, free the memory and continue with next lines?

Comment: That's what a friend recommended but also added that I try threading it. So that I had 2-3 threads doing 1000 lines a piece.

Comment: This sounds quite similar to your need. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38562082/how-to-read-millions-of-rows-from-the-text-file-and-insert-into-table-quickly

Comment: Maybe I'm oblivious but, to me, a 250 MB text file getting loaded into memory doesn't seem like it should take 4 GB to contain. I'm just not considering all the overhead of data types, pointers, etc. Am I?

Comment: There might be internals when it comes to datatype conversions and maintaining schema "might" take that much. Note that .Net objects are limited to 2 GB (or was it 1?). We are looking at plenty of objects here. Memory profiling might turn out to be your friend.