# Best way"less time" to bulk insert using entity framework excluding duplicated records for two related tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, ado

I am trying to bulk insert to tables "TU" and "TUV" (one to many relationship) with no duplicated records of "TU" table column "HashText" so I did this:

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Check if the selected TranslationUnit is exsists at db.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="translationUnit"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public bool CheckDuplicate(TranslationUnit translationUnit)
    {

        int FoundedTusCount = db.TUs.Where(tu => tu.HashText == translationUnit.Hash && TmIDList.Any(tm => tm == tu.TMID)).Count();
        if(FoundedTusCount > 0)
        {
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

this is a lot of connection to DB and a lot of time.

Then insert the remains items to the database using addRange() every 10000 (saving connection time)record like this:

```
            foreach (TranslationUnit item in Options.TMXFile.Data.Body.TranslationUnits.ToList())
            {
                TU tu = FillTU(TMID, item);
                ReadyTUs.Add(tu);
                tu.TUVs = new List<TUV>();
                foreach (TranslationUnitVariant item1 in item.TranslationUnitVariants)
                {
                    tu.TUVs.Add( FillTUV(item1));
                }
                if (ReadyTUs.Count >= 10000)
                {
                    Save();
                }
            }
            Save();
```

this is the save function:

```
    private void Save()
    {
        db.TUs.AddRange(ReadyTUs);
        db.SaveChanges();
        ReadyTUs.Clear();
        db.Dispose();
        db = new GTMEntities();
    }
```

My main problem now is time and many connections to DB So, if there is some way to bulk insert TU and TUV table with no duplicated TUs -that contains millions of records- it will be much better.

Comment: One idea is to bulk insert into a staging table TU_RAW, for example, everything.  Then do the actual insert into TU using a stored procedure.  That usually decreases time and lowers db connections.

Comment: If you can use SQL SERVER directly... it would be faster than Entity framework

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to use [SqlBulkCopy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly).

Basically you bulk insert all data into a staging table.

Then join the main and the staging tables and `DELETE` all records in the staging table that match.

Then `INSERT` into the real table with the results of a `SELECT DISTINCT` from the staging table.