# What would be the best practice of using azure functions to insert data into AzureSQLDB from Json string?

Tags: azure-sql-database, azure-functions

I am new to Azure Functions.I have a got a requirement to insert data into AzureSQLDB. The data I will get in the form of json by calling a restful api. I am planning to create a Timer Trigger function as this data transfer should be done once in a month automatically.I was wondering which approach should I take.

- Should I parse the json value into models in azure function and insert it one by one by executing query?
- Should I Send the whole json string to AzureSqlDB and querying the json and insert values in the table?
- Or is there any other approach considered as a best practice to this requirement?

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: How big is the batch in terms of # of rows?

Comment: Expecting to get at least 10000 rows at a time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There might be several opinions and approaches here, but I have at least a couple considerations:

- You *could* parse JSON inside SQL Server, but you probably shouldn't. Normally, it's better to leverage general-purpose programming language like C# with all the libraries, testability and pay for cheap CPU time instead of doing that in SQL
- Avoid making N separate database calls for N rows. With large number of rows the latency of many calls will accumulate pretty fast. Remember, that on Consumption plan you have max 10 minutes for a single Function invocation
- Debatable, but I would avoid heavy libraries like Entity Framework

I don't know the exact structure of you SQL table, but my default approach would be:

- Get the JSON
- Convert it to C# objects / validate / apply any logic or transformation
- Fill a plain ADO.NET `DataTable`
- Use `SqlBulkCopy` to insert data into SQL, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer.I tried this approach and find it very helpful.