# How to insert data table by stored procedure in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql-server

tried to insert many records of a data table to SQL table by stored procedure.I need insert data table's records all together.

I'm using C# programming language and i want to send many records to SQL server by ADO.net stored procedure all together. i want to know about data table types and use it if that helps me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Insert 2 million rows into SQL Server quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly)

Comment: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/nikhilsi/2008/06/11/bulk-insert-into-sql-from-c-app/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass many rows efficiently to a stored procedure, use a [table-valued parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/table-valued-parameters). The C# app can specify parameter type structured and a value of a data table. For maximum performance, make sure the `DataTable` column types match the server-side table type column types (including max length for string columns).

Below is an example excerpt from the documentation link above:

```
// Assumes connection is an open SqlConnection object.  
using (connection)  
{  
  // Create a DataTable with the modified rows.  
  DataTable addedCategories = CategoriesDataTable.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added);  

  // Configure the SqlCommand and SqlParameter.  
  SqlCommand insertCommand = new SqlCommand("usp_InsertCategories", connection);  
  insertCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;  
  SqlParameter tvpParam = insertCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tvpNewCategories", addedCategories);  
  tvpParam.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.Structured;  

  // Execute the command.  
  insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();  
}
```

Here are T-SQL snippets to create the table type and proc.

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.CategoryTableType AS TABLE  
    ( CategoryID int, CategoryName nvarchar(50) );
GO

CREATE PROC dbo.usp_InsertCategories
AS
@tvpNewCategories dbo.CategoryTableType READONLY
INSERT INTO dbo.Categories (CategoryID, CategoryName)  
    SELECT nc.CategoryID, nc.CategoryName FROM @tvpNewCategories AS nc;
GO
```

Even for trivial inserts, TVP performance can provide [performance similar to SqlBulkCopy](https://www.dbdelta.com/maximizing-performance-with-table-valued-parameters/) (many thousands per second) with the advantage of a stored procedure interface.