# Saving data in SQL with many conditions then retrieves data from SQL to compare with before saving each record

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, if-statement, sql-insert

Conditions are if this record already exist,
if the email in this record is valid or is in another table. 
i am looping data from excel sheet by uploading it and looping into records 
my code is working well and saving in database but the issue is that its taking to much time to finish the job like 4 days for comparing and saving 200k records...
i need a better way

```
var Email = dt.Rows[j][3].ToString();
                List<AllBounced> bounce = cnx.AllBounceds.Where(x => x.Email == Email).ToList();
                List<MainField> mainfield = cnx.MainFields.Where(x => x.Email == data.Email).ToList();
                List<MainField> mainfield2 = cnx.MainFields.Where(x => x.Phone == data.Phone || x.Mobile == data.Mobile).ToList();
                if (data.Email != null)
                {
                    if (IsEmailValid(Email) == true)
                    {
                        if (mainfield.Count != 0)
                        {
                            MainFieldsDuplicate data2 = new MainFieldsDuplicate
                            {
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                FirstName = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString(),
                                MiddleName = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString(),
                                LastName = dt.Rows[j][2].ToString(),
                                Email = dt.Rows[j][3].ToString(),
                                Phone = dt.Rows[j][4].ToString(),
                                Mobile = dt.Rows[j][5].ToString(),
                                a= dt.Rows[j][6].ToString(),
                                b= dt.Rows[j][7].ToString(),
                                c= dt.Rows[j][8].ToString(),
                                d= dt.Rows[j][9].ToString(),
                                e= dt.Rows[j][11].ToString(),
                                f= dt.Rows[j][12].ToString(),
                                j= dt.Rows[j][14].ToString(),
                                isDeleted = 0,
                                h= dt.Rows[j][13].ToString(),
                                Date = GetDateTime(dt.Rows[j][10].ToString()),
                            };
                            cnx.MainFieldsDuplicates.Add(data2);
                            cnx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (bounce.Count != 0)
                            {
                                data.isBounce = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.isBounce = false;
                            }
                            data.isValid = true;
                            cnx.MainFields.Add(data);
                            cnx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }

                    else
                    {
                        if (mainfield.Count != 0)
                        {
                            MainFieldsDuplicate data2 = new MainFieldsDuplicate
                            {
                                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                                FirstName = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString(),
                                MiddleName = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString(),
                                LastName = dt.Rows[j][2].ToString(),
                                Email = dt.Rows[j][3].ToString(),
                                Phone = dt.Rows[j][4].ToString(),
                                Mobile = dt.Rows[j][5].ToString(),
                                a= dt.Rows[j][6].ToString(),
                                b= dt.Rows[j][7].ToString(),
                                c= dt.Rows[j][8].ToString(),
                                d= dt.Rows[j][9].ToString(),
                                e = dt.Rows[j][11].ToString(),
                                f= dt.Rows[j][12].ToString(),
                                j= dt.Rows[j][14].ToString(),
                                isDeleted = 0,
                                h = dt.Rows[j][13].ToString(),
                                Date = GetDateTime(dt.Rows[j][10].ToString())
                            };
                            cnx.MainFieldsDuplicates.Add(data2);
                            cnx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            if (bounce.Count != 0)
                            {
                                data.isBounce = true;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                data.isBounce = false;
                            }
                            data.isValid = false;
                            cnx.MainFields.Add(data);
                            cnx.SaveChanges();
                        }
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (mainfield2.Count != 0)
                    {
                        MainFieldsDuplicate data3 = new MainFieldsDuplicate
                        {
                            Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                            FirstName = dt.Rows[j][0].ToString(),
                            MiddleName = dt.Rows[j][1].ToString(),
                            LastName = dt.Rows[j][2].ToString(),
                            Email = dt.Rows[j][3].ToString(),
                            Phone = dt.Rows[j][4].ToString(),
                            Mobile = dt.Rows[j][5].ToString(),
                            a= dt.Rows[j][6].ToString(),
                            b= dt.Rows[j][7].ToString(),
                            c= dt.Rows[j][8].ToString(),
                            d= dt.Rows[j][9].ToString(),
                            e= dt.Rows[j][11].ToString(),
                            f= dt.Rows[j][12].ToString(),
                            j= dt.Rows[j][14].ToString(),
                            isDeleted = 0,
                            h= dt.Rows[j][13].ToString(),
                            Date = GetDateTime(dt.Rows[j][10].ToString())
                        };
                        cnx.MainFieldsDuplicates.Add(data3);
                        cnx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cnx.MainFields.Add(data);
                        cnx.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

Comment: May be your looking for `SqlBulkCopy`  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=netframework-4.8

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly

Comment: I Guess not in my case 
because i found that the issue is probably with SQL now 
slow inserting for new records

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to profile your app to determine which parts you need to optimize, e.g. by just using the [Stopwatch Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netcore-2.2).

In your case, main suspects are the calls to the context, i.e. `SaveChanges` and `Where/ToList`.
One thing you could try is avoiding to call `SaveChanges` on the context in each iteration, see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58079317/saving-data-in-sql-with-many-conditions-then-retrieves-data-from-sql-to-compare).
Another thing would be (if feasable) to load the `AllBounced` and `MainField` lists upfront into memory.

Comment: Thank you 
i removed the SaveChanges and put it at then end of all the code and changed the List<> to a int that only take the count of the list 
so the performance is better 
but I realized that after 30 min running the process, I stopped the function 
but it took SQL all the night to finish inserting new records till now, 

So it seems that the issue is with SQL Queue
very slow to insert new records!!!

Comment: You can find tips for improving the insert performance in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework).