# How to bulk insert records into SQL server

Tags: c#, sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm trying to read a text file and then split each line as per it's significance which forms a particular record entry in my database table. I'm storing these records in a list and bulk insert the data from list to database. The file that I'm reading is of size ~18MB and has around 15,000 to 18,000 of lines . Below is the code :

```
StringBuilder logInsertCommand = new StringBuilder();
List<string> bulkLogInsert = new List<string>();
using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
using (BufferedStream bs = new BufferedStream(fs))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
{
    while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Perform some logic with `line` and get all the column values required for inserting a new record in database table. Values like FirstColumnValue, SecondColumnValue are obtained from the logic performed on `line` variable.
        logInsertCommand.Append(FirstColumnValue).Append(';').Append(SecondColumnValue).Append(';').Append(ThirdColumnValue).Append(';').Append(FourthColumnValue).Append(';').Append(FifthColumnValue);
        bulkLogInsert.Add(logInsertCommand.ToString());
    }
}

public void InsertBulkLog(List<string> records)
{
    try
    {
        String connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConString"];
        DataTable table = new DataTable("TORNADO_LOGS");
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FILENAME", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("PROJ_CODE", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("IS_RECORD_PROCESSED", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("FILE_LAST_MODIFIED_DATE", typeof(string)));
        table.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("MP3_FILE", typeof(string)));

        foreach (string record in records)
        {
            string[] rowParameters = record.Split(new char[] { ';' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            table.Rows.Add(rowParameters);
        }
        using (SqlBulkCopy bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(table);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Write to log
    }
}
```

My question here is that I'm storing the records (15k to 17k) in a container like list and then trying to bulk insert the data in SQL server I guess this is not so good approach so how can I efficiently insert this data into database? Any approach will be helpful.

Comment: Use the DataTable as the container, get rid of the List<string>

Comment: @rene Right now `InsertBulkLog` is in database class so if I construct `DataTable` in business logic class then will it be a good design idea?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13722014/insert-2-million-rows-into-sql-server-quickly

Comment: either that list or datatable acts as a DTO between your layers. The datatable it self doesn't need to have any knowledge about which database its rows will be stored to., heck, it can even persist as xml on disk. But if you care that much you can create a proper DTO class with 5 properties and add that to a list. Maybe you can make that DTO a bit more feature rich by having it do some of the line parsing.

Answer (score 0):

To fully stream the data from the file into SQL, you need to create a `IDataReader`.

There are many ways to do this, but the easiest is to use the NuGet FastMember library, which has `ObjectReader.Create`. This accepts an `IEnumerable<SomeType>` and returns a `IDataReader` which you can pass directly to `WriteToServer`. This means that each line is streamed into the Bulk Copy, and you never store the whole file in memory at once.

```cs
private IEnumerable<RecordLine> GetRecords()
{
    using (FileStream fs = File.Open(FilePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite))
    using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(bs, Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1")))
    {
        string line;
        while ((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            var rec = new RecordLine();
            // use logic to create a RecordLine object here
            yield return rec;
        }
    }
}

public void InsertBulkLog()
{
    try
    {
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["DBConString"];
        using (var reader = ObjectReader.Create(GetRecords());
        using (var bulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(connectionString))
        {
            bulkCopy.BulkCopyTimeout = 600;
            bulkCopy.DestinationTableName = table.TableName;
            bulkCopy.WriteToServer(reader);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Write to log
    }
}
```